# Create trigger when Column A equal Column B

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am try to create a trigger in SQL server to automatically insert a value in another column if Column A equals Column B, otherwise, insert another value in it.

For instance, if colA not equal colB, then insert 'Wrong' in column Score. If colA equal colB, then insert 'Correct' in column Score.

I tried this below, it does not work.

How do I change this to work?

```
CREATE TABLE testtrigger(
ID INT identity(1,1) primary key,
ColA varchar(50),
ColB varchar(50),
Score varchar(50)
);
GO

CREATE TRIGGER trgAfterInsertUpdate 
   ON testtrigger
   AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON;
   IF UPDATE, INSERT
   BEGIN
      UPDATE testtrigger
      SET Score = correct
      WHERE ColA = ColB
   ELSE
      SET Score = wrong
      WHERE ColA <> ColB
   END
END
```

Thanks.

Comment: Don't do this with triggers. Just make `Score` a computed column.

Comment: `SET Score = correct` - What is `correct`? Also note that column `Score` is declared as INT, but in the text above you use `'Correct'` with quotes.

Comment: Score should be varchar, sorry about that. Score = correct if colA and colB equals. How about score = wrong???

Comment: When some code you are posting "does not work" you should always include the error you get in your question.

Comment: first rule of thumb - don't *store* that which can be computed. It would appear that we can compute `Score` at any time using the other columns. second rule of thumb - if you "need" to store the value, prefer to use mechanisms where SQL Server automatically maintains the calculation. Here, as already suggested above, a computed column seems to be indicated.

Comment: You might have misunderstood my question. I don't total ColA and ColB. I need to specify one value, either Correct or Wrong at column Score. For instance, if colA not equal colB, then insert 'Wrong' in column Score. If colA equal colB, then insert 'Correct' in column Score. How do I compute when creating a table in SQL server? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CASE or IIF() in sql server Try this

```
   CREATE TRIGGER trgAfterInsertUpdate 
   ON testtrigger
   AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
   AS
   BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON;

      UPDATE t
      SET t.Score = (CASE WHEN t.ColA = t.ColB THEN  'Correct' 
                          WHEN  t.ColA <> t.ColB THEN 'Wrong' END)
      FROM testtrigger t
      INNER JOIN  inserted i ON t.ID=i.ID


      -- UPDATE t
      -- SET t.Score = (IIF( t.ColA = t.ColB,'Correct','Wrong'))
      -- FROM testtrigger t
      -- INNER JOIN  inserted i ON t.ID=i.ID

   END

INSERT INTO Testtrigger(ColA, ColB) VALUES
('G', 'G'),
('H', 'A');

SELECT *
FROM Testtrigger
```

Result

```
ID  ColA    ColB    Score
-------------------------
1   A        B      wrong
2   A        A      correct
3   G        G      correct
4   H        A      wrong
```

Comment: Happy to help bro :)

Comment: This definitely works but a trigger for this is overly complicated IMHO.

Answer (score 4):

How about making the `Score` computed column as

```
CREATE TABLE testtrigger(
ID INT identity(1,1) primary key,
ColA varchar(50),
ColB varchar(50),
Score AS CASE WHEN ISNULL(ColA, 0) = ISNULL(ColB, 0) THEN 'Correct' ELSE 'Wrong' END
);

INSERT INTO Testtrigger(ColA, ColB) VALUES
('A', 'B'),
('A', 'A');

SELECT *
FROM Testtrigger;
```

Update:

If you already create your table then you can do

```
ALTER TABLE testtrigger
DROP COLUMN Score;

ALTER TABLE testtrigger
ADD Score AS CASE WHEN ISNULL(ColA, 0) = ISNULL(ColB, 0) THEN 'Correct' ELSE 'Wrong' END PERSISTED;
```

Comment: You should make that computed column PERSISTED or have an index on that column, or else this will be terribly slow when querying

Comment: Since I already created this table. I clicked on table design of sql server, click on this column, change Is Persisted to yes, then I entered this formular at Computed column to be AS CASE WHEN ColA = ColB THEN 'Correct' ELSE 'Wrong' END, but it won't let me save it.

Comment: Then stop using the table designer. Do this with t-sql. It is faster and simpler once you get used to it. Using a computed column like this is definitely the best way to go. Make it PERSISTED and this would be just what you need.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot set to `int Score` column a `varchar` value, however you can set `0` or `1` values. `0` means wrong, `1` means correct.
Let me show an example:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trgAfterInsertUpdate 
   ON testtrigger
   AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON;
   IF UPDATE(ColA)   
   BEGIN      
      UPDATE t
      SET score = CASE 
                    WHEN t.ColA = i.ColB THEN 1
                    ELSE 0
                  END
      FROM dbo.testtrigger t
      INNER JOIN INSERTed i ON t.ID = i.ID    
   END
END
```

or just change your `Score` column to `VARCHAR(20)`:

```
CREATE TABLE testtrigger(
ID INT identity(1,1) primary key,
ColA varchar(50),
ColB varchar(50),
Score varchar(20)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

i think you just miss ' in the set

```
CREATE TABLE testtrigger(
ID INT identity(1,1) primary key,
ColA varchar(50),
ColB varchar(50),
Score varchar(50)
);
GO

CREATE TRIGGER trgAfterInsertUpdate 
   ON testtrigger
   AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON

   UPDATE testtrigger
   SET Score = 'correct'
   WHERE ColA = ColB

   UPDATE testtrigger
   SET Score = 'wrong'
   WHERE ColA <> ColB

END
```

Comment: You should definitely add a "FROM INSERTED" to only update the inserted/updated rows. Also, isn't there a second "UPDATE testtrigger" missing in the else block?

Comment: Is your intent to really update EVERY row in the table `testtrigger` every time time there is an `INSERT` or `UPDATE` (I suspect not).

Comment: I'm also not sure that `int` is right for a column we're trying to set to `correct` or `wrong`.

Comment: I need only update for new inserts. I changed Score to be varchar. Thanks.